# Usergrid is failed to start. usergrid.cluster_name property must be set

Tags: usergrid

I am trying to setup Usergrid 2.1.0. I downloaded binaries and trying to setup with tomcat, cassandra and elasticsearch. I am following [this](https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/deployment-guide.html). i created 'usergrid-default.properties' and saved in my 'tomcat_home/lib' folder. when i going to start the server, it is throwing the exception

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usergrid.cluster_name property must be set.
  at org.apache.usergrid.persistence.core.guice.SettingsValidationCluster.<init>(SettingsValidationCluster.java:17)
at org.apache.usergrid.persistence.core.guice.CommonModule.configure(CommonModule.java:98) (via modules: org.apache.usergrid.corepersistence.CoreModule -> org.apache.usergrid.persistence.core.guice.CommonModule)
while locating org.apache.usergrid.persistence.core.guice.SettingsValidationCluster
```

i have added a property 'usergrid.cluster_name' but it is still not working. can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this issue. as i had properties file 'usergrid-default'. It should be 'usergrid-deployment'. I renamed and things are working.